# Which Spring annotation to use for Hibernate DAO class?

Tags: spring, layer, spring-annotations

What Spring annotation should I use for Hibernate DAO classes so they could be found in scanning process? @Repository, @Service or @Component? I couldn't figure out the difference. I'm on Spring 2.5.6 now.

P.S. Can someone guide me quickly through the layer idea? I only have heard a thing like presentation layer, but don't have exact understanding what should I call so and what is the business layer? Are there other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Repository` would be my recommendation.

Presentation tier means web UI, so those should use the `@Controller` annotation.

Services implement use cases using POJO interfaces; mark this as `@Service`.  Controllers will use services to fulfill use cases.

Comment: By the way, do i need to place it on DAOImpl or just DAO?

Comment: Add it to the impl: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/11/27/annotation-based-configuration-spring

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter much, but `@Repository` is a good bet.  The [Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) has this to say:

> Beginning with Spring 2.0, the
>   @Repository annotation was introduced
>   as a marker for any class that
>   fulfills the role or stereotype of a
>   repository (a.k.a. Data Access Object
>   or DAO)

Answer (score 0):

In core Spring, I don't believe there is any difference. Generally, these stereotype annotations are used for `auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning` (from Spring docs). It is possible to have some software to make use of them but in absence of such software I choose stereotype that makes most sense to me. In case of DAO I usually choose `@Component`, although `@Repository` is a good option as well.